# socket.io - transport close

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Our real time chat service consists of client socket.io connections that throughout the have 'random' client disconnect with a disconnect reason on the server side of 'transport close'.  We occasionally see 'ping timeout' and 'namespace disonnect' which happens when the server can no longer ping the client and the user logs off respectively.  We are struggling to understand why the 'transport close' disconnects are happening though.

Here are the socket options used by the client to connect,

```
var socketOptions = {
transports: ['websocket'],
query: 'token=' + JSON.stringify(token) + '&member=' + 
       JSON.stringify(memberService.currentMember) + '&isBrowser=' + 
       isBrowser + '&isBrowserFocused=' + isBrowserFocused,
reconnectionAttempts: 5
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the version of "socket.io" with "socket.io-client".
If server / client version is mismatch, the connection was very unstable.

I recommend simply using CDN like below for client.

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.slim.js"></script>`

@ref: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io

I hope it helps.

Comment: I am having the same problem and in both the server and the client I use socket.io version 2.0.4